# How to group area chart extremes for x-axis dynamically with day,week,months value in highstock

Tags: highcharts

Need to display area chart in with highstocks for 1 day,1 week,1 month,6 month,1year and 5 years providing the data at once for all the 5 years.But in case of day it is displaying date with time on x-axis which is not required.How can this date be removed as only time is to be displayed (Eg 9 10 11 ....4 5)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPositioner which allows to set tick, dynamically, based on your data and function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner